# Java: interact with another process

Tags: java, process

If I have a random program, that shows some text and has some text input, is there a way to write a java program, that reads that text labels and/or fill that text input fields and press an ok button?

Comment: could you explain with some working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text applications are things that run on the cli, and have no windows.  On Microsoft Windows the 'dir' command is an example.

Graphical applications are things that the beginning user might see, and has buttons, text boxes, scroll bars and stuff like that.  On Microsoft Windows the 'paint' program is an example.

Web applications are websites that provide front ends as web pages.  The 'gmail' application is an example.

If you want to interact with an application using Java, the application type will determine your approach.

- text application - use ProcessBuilder, it's a java class designed to launch and (to a degree) interact with processes through stdin, stderr, and stdout.
- Graphical application - It depends on the graphical widgets the application uses.  If those are not supported by a library that can navigate the presentation, then input is limited to x,y coordinates from the application's origin, and input could fail to go into the right component.
- Web applications - Use selenium.  It is a custom web browser solution that permits testing of web sites; but, you could use it for your task.  It is big and complicated, but considering what is required for this task, it is comparatively easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write a new program that can give input and trigger the service of 'OK' key.

Your first program needs to be designed in the way that - it should accept the input from second program.

You can design the first code as web service in a web application . your first program will be web service provider  and second program will be web service consumer.

Using second program you can post the required data to first code. and all the triggers of 'OK' button can be processed from first application.